Convert SVG link to the format in css
I have css like this below,
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2024%2024%22%3E%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M23.7%2020.8%2019%2016.1c-.2-.2-.5-.3-.8-.3h-.8c1.3-1.7%202-3.7%202-6C19.5%204.4%2015.1%200%209.7%200S0%204.4%200%209.7s4.4%209.7%209.7%209.7c2.3%200%204.3-.8%206-2v.8c0%20.3.1.6.3.8l4.7%204.7c.4.4%201.2.4%201.6%200l1.3-1.3c.5-.5.5-1.2.1-1.6zm-14-5.1c-3.3%200-6-2.7-6-6s2.7-6%206-6%206%202.7%206%206-2.6%206-6%206z%22%20fill%3D%22%23767d83%22%3E%3C%2Fpath%3E%20%3C%2Fsvg%3E');

It shows the magnifying glass icon.
Now I want to change this icon to home button.
I can find the icon on fontawesome page and get the link
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.6.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1l-32 0 .7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1l0 16.2c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-16 0c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1L416 512l-24 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-24 0-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64 0c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32l0 64 0 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-24 0-31.9 0c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2l-16 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-112c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8l0-69.7-32 0c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z"/></svg>

However this is the bit different the one I got in css.
Is it convertable? or am I wrong from the begginng?

you "just" have to change some characters : < -> %3C,  [space character] -> %20 etc...

Here's an useful website that I always use ;)

@MisterJojo actually these are fine. The ones they need to handle are % (-> %25), : (->  %3A) , and # (-> %23). I might miss some, but I think it's the whole list.

Yes it is convertible.
The css url function expects a absolute URL, a relative URL, a blob URL, or a data URL. In your example the css is using a Data URL, URLs prefixed with the data: scheme, allow content creators to embed small files inline in documents..
We can surely build a data URL from that svg by following the expected syntax.

Note: the svg must contain xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"

data:[<mediatype>][;encoding],<data>


mediatype for svg is image/svg+xml. from Common MIME types

encoding can be omitted but let's use charset=utf8

data has to be encoded. The easiest way will be to use encodeURIComponent("<svg...")


Putting all together:


let mySvg = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><!--!Font Awesome Free 6.6.0 by @fontawesome - https://fontawesome.com License - https://fontawesome.com/license/free Copyright 2024 Fonticons, Inc.--><path d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1l-32 0 .7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1l0 16.2c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-16 0c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1L416 512l-24 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-24 0-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64 0c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32l0 64 0 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-24 0-31.9 0c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2l-16 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-112c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8l0-69.7-32 0c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z"/></svg>
`;

// ensure xmlns attr
if (!mySvg.includes('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"')) {
  mySvg = mySvg.replace('<svg', '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"');
}

const encoding = "charset=utf8";
const mediaType = "image/svg+xml";
const data = encodeURIComponent(mySvg);

const dataURL = `data:${mediaType};${encoding},${data}`;

const el = document.getElementById("my");
el.style.background = `url(${dataURL})`;
#my {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
<div id="my"></div>




you can use  encodeURIComponent()...
the full process:
(remove the comments ; <!--!Font Awesome ..... )


const svgTxt = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 576 512"><path d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1l-32 0 .7 160.2c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1l0 16.2c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-16 0c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1L416 512l-24 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-24 0-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64 0c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32l0 64 0 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-24 0-31.9 0c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2l-16 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-112c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8l0-69.7-32 0c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z"/></svg>`


document.querySelector('pre')
  .textContent = encodeURIComponent(svgTxt);
svg { 
  width : 5em; 
  fill: orange; 
  }
div {
  width  : 5em; 
  height : 5em; 
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%20576%20512%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M575.8%20255.5c0%2018-15%2032.1-32%2032.1l-32%200%20.7%20160.2c0%202.7-.2%205.4-.5%208.1l0%2016.2c0%2022.1-17.9%2040-40%2040l-16%200c-1.1%200-2.2%200-3.3-.1c-1.4%20.1-2.8%20.1-4.2%20.1L416%20512l-24%200c-22.1%200-40-17.9-40-40l0-24%200-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64%200c-17.7%200-32%2014.3-32%2032l0%2064%200%2024c0%2022.1-17.9%2040-40%2040l-24%200-31.9%200c-1.5%200-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2%20.1-2.4%20.2-3.6%20.2l-16%200c-22.1%200-40-17.9-40-40l0-112c0-.9%200-1.9%20.1-2.8l0-69.7-32%200c-18%200-32-14-32-32.1c0-9%203-17%2010-24L266.4%208c7-7%2015-8%2022-8s15%202%2021%207L564.8%20231.5c8%207%2012%2015%2011%2024z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  }
initial svg : <br>
<svg viewBox="0 0 576 512">
  <path d="M575.8 255.5c0 18-15 32.1-32 32.1l-32 0 .7 160.2
  c0 2.7-.2 5.4-.5 8.1l0 16.2c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-16 0
  c-1.1 0-2.2 0-3.3-.1c-1.4 .1-2.8 .1-4.2 .1L416 512l-24 0
  c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40l0-24 0-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64 0
  c-17.7 0-32 14.3-32 32l0 64 0 24c0 22.1-17.9 40-40 40l-24 0-31.9 0
  c-1.5 0-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2 .1-2.4 .2-3.6 .2l-16 0c-22.1 0-40-17.9-40-40
  l0-112c0-.9 0-1.9 .1-2.8l0-69.7-32 0c-18 0-32-14-32-32.1c0-9 3-17 10-24
  L266.4 8c7-7 15-8 22-8s15 2 21 7L564.8 231.5c8 7 12 15 11 24z"/>
</svg>
<br><br><br><br>
svg encoded text:
<pre></pre>

<br><br><br><br>
result:
<div></div>



to set your own color
use CSS mask-image.
(also set viewbox to 0 0 576 576)


div {
  width  : 5em; 
  height : 5em;
  background-color  : red;
  mask-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf8,%3Csvg%20xmlns=%22http://www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%20viewBox=%220%200%20576%20576%22%3E%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M575.8%20255.5c0%2018-15%2032.1-32%2032.1l-32%200%20.7%20160.2c0%202.7-.2%205.4-.5%208.1l0%2016.2c0%2022.1-17.9%2040-40%2040l-16%200c-1.1%200-2.2%200-3.3-.1c-1.4%20.1-2.8%20.1-4.2%20.1L416%20512l-24%200c-22.1%200-40-17.9-40-40l0-24%200-64c0-17.7-14.3-32-32-32l-64%200c-17.7%200-32%2014.3-32%2032l0%2064%200%2024c0%2022.1-17.9%2040-40%2040l-24%200-31.9%200c-1.5%200-3-.1-4.5-.2c-1.2%20.1-2.4%20.2-3.6%20.2l-16%200c-22.1%200-40-17.9-40-40l0-112c0-.9%200-1.9%20.1-2.8l0-69.7-32%200c-18%200-32-14-32-32.1c0-9%203-17%2010-24L266.4%208c7-7%2015-8%2022-8s15%202%2021%207L564.8%20231.5c8%207%2012%2015%2011%2024z%22%2F%3E%3C%2Fsvg%3E');
  }
<div></div>




It's encodeURIComponent, not encodeURI: https://jsfiddle.net/rgy5w4n8/  The issue is the # character. Here I used it for a color, but it can also appear in local href.

@Kaiido oh... thanks! ;) updated my answer with encodeURIComponent() results
